# como pegar a palavra do link clicado e mandar para a pagina que o link manda

Tags: php, html, link

Não sei se a pergunta ficou clara, mas vamos la. estou com esse codigo aqui:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <META CHARSET="UTF-8">
  <META NAME="author" VALUE="Fernando Aguiar Pinedo">
  <LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="css.css">
  <LINK REL="shortcut icon" HREF="favicon.ico">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="cabeçalho">
   <h1>Music Downloader</h1>
   <p>Download Your Music Here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="filterlist">
   <ul>
    <h1 style="font-family:calibri; margin:5px; text-align:center;">Genre</h1>
    <li>Rock</li>
    <li>Eletronic</li>
    <li>Pop</li>
    <li>Reggae</li>
    <li>Hip Hop</li>
    <li>Anime</li>
    <li>Video Game</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <h1 style="font-family:calibri; margin:5px; text-align:center;">Language</h1>
    <li>English</li>
    <li>Japanese</li>
    <li>French</li>
    <li>Brazilian</li>
    <li>Chinese</li>
    <li>German</li>
    <li>Spanish</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content"> <!--Conteúdo Aqui-->
   <?php
    include ("connectsql.php");
    $busca = "SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id < 11";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $busca) or die(mysqli_error());
 
    if($result){
     while($song = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo "<div style=font-family:calibri;color:#FFFFFF;text-shadow:1px.3px.6px;display:inline-block;width:50%;>";
      echo "<a style='text-decoration:none;color:inherit;'href=http://localhost/sitededownload/pagdownload.php>
      <h2 style= margin:0px;margin-top:10px;>$song[Song]</h2>
      </a>";
      echo "<p style= margin:0;>$song[Artista]</p>";
      echo "</div>";
     }
    }
   ?>
  </div> <!--Até Aqui-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Quero saber como que eu faço para pegar a palavra do link que eu cliquei na tag (a) dentro do **php** e colocar como titulo na pagina `pagdownload.php`.

Como são varias palavras na pagina `pagdownload.php` que eu preciso fazer um link para uma pagina semelhante, pensei em fazer uma pagina apenas que se altera de acordo com o item que foi clicado, mas não sei se é possível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode passar a palavra desejada como parâmetro no link e pegar na `pagdownload.php`

```
echo "<a style='text-decoration:none;color:inherit;'href=http://localhost/sitededownload/pagdownload.php?title={$song[Song]}'>
    <h2 style= margin:0px;margin-top:10px;>{$song[Song]}</h2>
</a>";
```

E em `pagdownload.php` você pega este parametro utilizando o `$_GET`

```
$titulo = $_GET["title"];
```

Comment: Deu certo, não tinha nem ideia de como fazer, Muito Obrigado!!!!!!!